# WPF annotations load to XPS

Tags: c#, wpf, annotations, xps

In a process of investigation of using  AnnotationService Class with XML Paper Specification (XPS), I tried to save and load created annotations. With the Save annotations - all is simple (it's [described on microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.annotations.annotationservice?view=netframework-4.8)), but with load - not any information (absent any methods "Read"/"Write").
Exist some methods "Read"/"Write" for AnnotationResource Class, but i cannot understand how it can be using to load annotation for using after with Annotation Service Class.
If you know, who it will be work, interesting to see on it?

Answer (score 0):

I found some workaround for load early created annotations to XPS:
I created separated class `MyAnnotationStore` (because `XmlStreamStore` is sealed) with constructors and three methods:

- EnableAnnotations() - simple enable annotation (temporary storing in MemoryStream);
- SaveAnnotations() - save annotation to FileStream;
- LoadAnnotations() - load annotation from FileStream and enable    annotation;

Note on `_storeMemory.Position = 0;` without it annotations isn't correctly save or load

```
    public class MyAnnotationStore 
    {
     XmlStreamStore _storeXML;
     MemoryStream _storeMemory;
     AnnotationService _anoService;

    public MyAnnotationStore(FlowDocumentReader myDocumentReader)
    {
        // Create the AnnotationService object that works
        // with our FlowDocumentReader.
        _anoService = new AnnotationService(myDocumentReader);

        // Create a MemoryStream which will hold the annotations.
        _storeMemory = new MemoryStream();
    }

    public void EnableAnnotations()
    {
        // Now, create a XML-based store based on the MemoryStream.
        // You could use this object to programmatically add, delete
        // or find annotations.
        _storeXML = new XmlStreamStore(_storeMemory);

        // Enable the annotation services.
        _anoService.Enable(_storeXML);
    }


    public void SaveAnnotations()
    {
        _storeXML.Flush();
        _storeMemory.Flush();
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("StickNotes.xml", FileMode.Create))
        {
            _storeMemory.Position = 0;
            _storeMemory.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }

    public void LoadAnnotations()
    {
        FileStream fileStream = null;
        try
        {
            fileStream = new FileStream("StickNotes.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            fileStream.CopyTo(_storeMemory);
            _storeMemory.Position = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error File Read", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fileStream != null) fileStream.Close();
        }

        // Enable the annotation services after loading annotations from fileStream
        EnableAnnotations();
     }

    }
```

For testing purpose code-behind

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        MyAnnotationStore anoStore;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Create object for manipulate with annotations in myDocumentReader (load and create)
            anoStore = new MyAnnotationStore(myDocumentReader);
        }
}
```

and XAML

```
<FlowDocumentReader x:Name="myDocumentReader" Height="238.9">
                        <FlowDocument>
                            <Section>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    Here are some fun facts about the WPF Document API!
                                </Paragraph>
                            </Section>
                        </FlowDocument>
                    </FlowDocumentReader>
```